# Add input box for inline edit dynamically

Tags: jquery

I wrote the following code for dynamic table with inline edit.
In which I am editing only second `td` of a row.So I want to display that which `td` I am editing.Trying to add input but when `edit` button is clicked.Similarly I want to `hide` that `input box` when update button is clicked.
Please any help.

```
function editData() {
    $('.update').hide();
    $('.edit').click(function () {
        debugger
        var editId = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#" + editId).hide();
        var number = editId.replace("edit", "");
        $("#update" + number).show();

        var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find(':nth-child(2)');
        $.each(currentTD, function () {
            $(this).prop('contenteditable', true)
        });
    });

    $('.update').click(function () {

        var updateId = $(this).attr('id');
        $("#" + updateId).hide();
        var number = updateId.replace("update", "");
        $("#edit" + number).show();

        var currentTD = $(this).parents('tr').find(':nth-child(2)');

        $.each(currentTD, function () {
            $(this).prop('contenteditable', false)
        });


    });

}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wjb0an9m/

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: There is a pplugin which does exactly what you want: https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/demo-bs3.html?c=inline

Comment: Here is the updated fiddle, hope that helps https://jsfiddle.net/wjb0an9m/2/

Comment: @hunzaboy see my fiddle,In that when I click `edit` button second `td` of a row will be `contenteditable`.Along with this I want to add `textbox` that is when I click `edit` data of second `td ` of a row should be displayed inside a text box.

Comment: @GHOST93 I want to show content inside the textbox.

Comment: @krish https://jsfiddle.net/wjb0an9m/4/ hope this helps

Comment: @GHOST93 Can you help me to add just border for td instead of adding text box please

Comment: @krish I guess that can be achieved with proper styling (CSS) and I am not that good at css. You can take help of designer for that.